# Field Validation in EditorGrid

Tags: gxt

Let's start with saying that I'm using GXT 2.2.5 on GWT 2.3.0.

My goal is to present the user with a set of data retrieved from a query where he needs to specify a value for one of the fields. As an example, let's say the query returns a list of phone numbers, and the user needs to sepcify the type of number (i.e., Home, Office, Cell, or Pager) each is.

So I'm looking at the EditorGrid as a potential solution. The grid would display the type and number, with a ComboBox attached to the first field through a CellEditor.

The requirement is that the user must select a type for each number. How do I enforce this? I can set allowBlank to false on the ComboBox, but how do I manage it? How do I validate the grid?

I've searched for an answer, but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of the **Grid**, not the **EditorGrid**. When using a **RowEditor** within the **Grid** the allowBlank validation (or any other fields validator) are fired when the user saves row changes.

Here is a little example in case you are not familiar with the Grid:

```
ColumnConfig colNombre = new ColumnConfig("name", "Name", 200);
            TextField<String> txtNombre = new TextField<String>();
            txtNombre.setAllowBlank(false);
            txtNombre.getMessages().setBlankText("IT CANT BE EMPTY.");
            colNombre.setEditor(new CellEditor(txtNombre));
            configs.add(colNombre);



re = new RowEditor<BeanModel>();
        re.addListener(Events.AfterEdit, new Listener<RowEditorEvent>() {
            public void handleEvent(RowEditorEvent e) {
                editar(e);
            }
        });
        re.setClicksToEdit(ClicksToEdit.TWO);

        grid = new Grid<BeanModel>(STORE, new ColumnModel(configs));
        grid.addPlugin(re);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `SimpleComboBox<String>` to store all types of numbers (Home, Office etc). Attach it to the `EditorGrid`. Set the `setEditable(false)` property for `SimpleComboBox<String>`, and make sure that a valid "type" is selected by default in the combo-box (using `setValue(...)`).

In this way, when your Grid gets rendered, the phone numbers will have type beside them, having a default value selected.

I feel that this is a good approach, rather than having combobox with blank value initially, and then asking user to fill it by showing validation error.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it encourages users to get lazy and not truly determine which type of number it really is. I need to make sure they actively select a choice and not just leave it to some arbitrary default value.